What is the probability that Brownian motion hits $\mathbb{Q}^d$?
Let $B$ be a standard $d$-dimensional Brownian motion. What is $\mathbb{P}(\exists t > 0 : B_t \in \mathbb{Q}^d)$?
For $d = 1$, this is clearly $1$. However, intuitively, it seems that it should be $0$ for $d \ge 2$.
It is easy to see that, for $t>0$ fixed, $\mathbb{P}(B_t \in \mathbb{Q}^d) = 0$, which further implies that $B_t$ is almost surely not a rational point for $t$ in any countable set of times. However, it is not clear how to extend this to all $t > 0$. Indeed, a purely distributional argument will not work because the claim does not hold for for $d=1$.

@Masacroso Yes, it is worth a shot. I am thinking about the problem.

It is sufficient to show that, for any fixed $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$, a $d$-dimensional Brownian motion will never hit $x$ almost surely; $\mathbb{P}(B_t = x \text{ for some } t >0) = 0$. Then the result you are looking for follows by countable subadditivity (over $x \in \mathbb{Q}^d$).
For $d=2$, it is a standard result that Brownian motion does not hit points. For $d>2$, $x = (x_1,x_2,\dots, x_d)$, and Brownian motion $B = (B^1,B^2,\dots,B^d)$, we have
$$\mathbb{P}(B_t = x \text{ for some } t>0) \leq \mathbb{P}((B_t^1, B_t^2) = (x_1,x_2) \text{ for some } t > 0) = 0.$$

Thanks, I'm not sure how I forgot this result.
